# I have a Problem in parsing OWL to Prolog Triples

Tags: ros, knowrobtutorials, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

(((1)))I do not have more experience in KnowRob, so I now try to run command and see its effects and so on
I was trying to parse Owl file into Prolog so I use this command

```
 owl_parse('home/amal/pizza.owl', false, false, true).
```

I get this error

```
   bash: syntax error near unexpected token `'home/amal/pizza.owl','
```

1- What is the Problem

2- I do not Understand Why false false true in the command ?!

---

(((2))) It always give me false, I flow this tutorial (Reasoning about objects at knowrob wiki) and also get false, so what is the problem

---

Terminal:

```
amal@amal-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$ roscd knowrob_tutorial
amal@amal-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~/ros/pkgs/tum-ros-pkg/knowledge/knowrob_tutorial$ rosrun rosprolog rosprolog knowrob_tutorial
% library(swi_hooks) compiled into pce_swi_hooks 0.00 sec, 2,224 bytes
%     library(error) compiled into error 0.00 sec, 10,220 bytes
%    library(lists) compiled into lists 0.00 sec, 25,320 bytes
%   library(shlib) compiled into shlib 0.00 sec, 37,148 bytes
%   library(option) compiled into swi_option 0.00 sec, 8,468 bytes
%  library(process) compiled into process 0.00 sec, 55,748 bytes
% /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/rosprolog/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 60,268 bytes
%     library(jpl) compiled into jpl 0.02 sec, 171,488 bytes
%         library(sgml) compiled into sgml 0.01 sec, 25,072 bytes
%           library(quintus) compiled into quintus 0.00 sec, 11,676 bytes
%          rewrite compiled into rewrite 0.00 sec, 19,736 bytes
%          library(uri) compiled into uri 0.00 sec, 8,060 bytes
%          library(record) compiled into record 0.00 sec, 19,532 bytes
%         rdf_parser compiled into rdf_parser 0.01 sec, 87,476 bytes
%          library(gensym) compiled into gensym 0.00 sec, 2,580 bytes
%         rdf_triple compiled into rdf_triple 0.00 sec, 22,132 bytes
%        library(rdf) compiled into rdf 0.02 sec, 154,404 bytes
%         library(debug) compiled into prolog_debug 0.01 sec, 12,180 bytes
%         library(assoc) compiled into assoc 0.00 sec, 19,484 bytes
%        library(sgml_write) compiled into sgml_write 0.01 sec, 68,120 bytes
%        library(nb_set) compiled into nb_set 0.00 sec, 3,400 bytes
%         library(utf8) compiled into utf8 0.00 sec, 7,108 bytes
%        library(url) compiled into url 0.01 sec, 63,416 bytes
%        rdf_cache compiled into rdf_cache 0.01 sec, 9,016 bytes
%       library(semweb/rdf_db) compiled into rdf_db 0.05 sec, 398,008 bytes
%      comp_similarity compiled into comp_similarity 0.06 sec, 414,548 bytes
%     /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_prolog_addons/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.06 sec, 415,236 bytes
%      library(broadcast) compiled into broadcast 0.00 sec, 4,156 bytes
%     library(semweb/rdf_edit) compiled into rdf_edit 0.01 sec, 48,796 bytes
%     library(semweb/rdfs) compiled into rdfs 0.00 sec, 14,256 bytes
%     library(semweb/owl) compiled into t20_owl 0.01 sec, 37,936 bytes
%       library(socket) compiled into socket 0.00 sec, 7,060 bytes
%       library(base64) compiled into base64 0.00 sec, 9,640 bytes
%      library(http/http_open.pl) compiled into http_open 0.01 sec, 60,712 bytes
%     library(thea/owl_parser) compiled into owl_parser 0.02 sec, 108,668 bytes
%      library(odbc) compiled into odbc 0.01 sec, 21,856 bytes
%     library(semweb/rdfs_computable) compiled into rdfs_computable 0.01 sec, 58,556 bytes
%    /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/semweb/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.15 sec, 905,400 bytes
%        library(tf_prolog) compiled into tf_prolog 0.00 sec, 12,888 bytes
%       /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/tf_prolog/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.01 sec, 15,264 bytes
%        library(knowrob_owl) compiled into knowrob_owl 0.00 sec, 7,420 bytes
%        library(knowrob_perception) compiled into knowrob_perception 0.00 sec, 13,176 bytes
% Parsed "knowrob_objects.owl" in 0.00 sec; 202 triples
Warning: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/knowrob_objects/prolog/knowrob_objects.pl:84:
    Goal (directive) failed: knowrob_objects:owl_parser:owl_parse(../owl/knowrob_objects.owl,false,false,true)
%       library(knowrob_objects) compiled into knowrob_objects 0.02 sec, 109,092 bytes
%        library(owl_export) compiled into owl_export 0.00 sec, 11,660 bytes
%       library(knowrob_coordinates) compiled into knowrob_coordinates 0.00 sec, 23,832 bytes
%      /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/knowrob_objects/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.04 sec, 163,708 bytes
%      library(knowrob_actions) compiled into knowrob_actions 0.00 sec, 7,012 bytes
%     /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/knowrob_actions/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.04 sec, 184,588 bytes
%      library(util) compiled into util 0.00 sec, 15,440 bytes
%     library(classifiers) compiled into classifiers 0.01 sec, 29,576 bytes
%     library(jython) compiled into jython 0.00 sec, 13,348 bytes
% Parsed "owl.owl" in 0.01 sec; 169 triples
Warning: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_knowledge_base/prolog/init.pl:35:
    Goal (directive) failed: user:owl_parser:owl_parse(/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_knowledge_base/owl/owl.owl,false,false,true)
% Parsed "knowrob.owl" in 0.10 sec; 3,763 triples
Warning: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_knowledge_base/prolog/init.pl:36:
    Goal (directive) failed: user:owl_parser:owl_parse(/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_knowledge_base/owl/knowrob.owl,false,false,true)
%    /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_knowledge_base/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.16 sec, 440,920 bytes
%   /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/knowrob_common/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.31 sec, 1,364,368 bytes
%   library(mod_vis) compiled into mod_vis 0.00 sec, 20,000 bytes
%  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/mod_vis/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.31 sec, 1,395,712 bytes
% Parsed "comp_temporal.owl" in 0.00 sec; 164 triples
Warning: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/comp_temporal/prolog/comp_temporal.pl:74:
    Goal (directive) failed: comp_temporal:owl_parser:owl_parse(../owl/comp_temporal.owl,false,false,true)
%     library(comp_temporal) compiled into comp_temporal 0.02 sec, 23,848 bytes
Warning: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/comp_temporal/prolog/init.pl:30:
    Goal (directive) failed: user:owl_parser:owl_parse(/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/comp_temporal/owl/comp_temporal.owl,false,false,true)
%    /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/comp_temporal/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.02 sec, 27,240 bytes
% Parsed "comp_spatial.owl" in 0.00 sec; 52 triples
Warning: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/comp_spatial/prolog/comp_spatial.pl:51:
    Goal (directive) failed: comp_spatial:owl_parser:owl_parse(../owl/comp_spatial.owl,false,false,true)
%    library(comp_spatial) compiled into comp_spatial 0.01 sec, 24,664 bytes
Warning: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/comp_spatial/prolog/init.pl:32:
    Goal (directive) failed: user:owl_parser:owl_parse(/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/comp_spatial/owl/comp_spatial.owl,false,false,true)
%   /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/comp_spatial/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.04 sec, 69,000 bytes
%    library(semweb/actionmodel) compiled into actionmodel 0.01 sec, 62,984 bytes
% Parsed "ccrl2_semantic_map.owl" in 0.07 sec; 2,976 triples
Warning: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_semantic_map/prolog/ccrl2_semantic_map.pl:27:
    Goal (directive) failed: user:owl_parser:owl_parse(/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_semantic_map/owl/ccrl2_semantic_map.owl,false,false,true)
%   ccrl2_semantic_map compiled 0.08 sec, 110,248 bytes
%   semantic_map_utils compiled into ias_semantic_map 0.00 sec, 8,520 bytes
%  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_semantic_map/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.12 sec, 201,340 bytes
%  library(tabletop_obj) compiled into tabletop_obj 0.00 sec, 8,044 bytes
% Parsed "tabletop_obj.owl" in 0.00 sec; 4 triples
Warning: /home/amal/ros/pkgs/tum-ros-pkg/knowledge/knowrob_tutorial/prolog/init.pl:31:
    Goal (directive) failed: user:owl_parser:owl_parse(/home/amal/ros/pkgs/tum-ros-pkg/knowledge/knowrob_tutorial/owl/tabletop_obj.owl,false,false,true)
% /home/amal/ros/pkgs/tum-ros-pkg/knowledge/knowrob_tutorial/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.44 sec, 1,633,692 bytes
?- owl_parse('owl/ccrl2_map_objects.owl', false, false, true).
% Parsed "ccrl2_map_objects.owl" in 0.01 sec; 344 triples
false.
```

Thanks In Advance,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48492/i-have-a-problem-in--parsing-owl-to-prolog-triples/) by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2012-11-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-16**:
I want to edit the Q, but does not want to do this and say "Could not post, because your karma is insufficient to publish links " I does not add links it is just a copy from my terminal, I was can do this in normal but does not know what is the problem now ?! so why?!

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-16**:
What I want to edit I run 'roswtf' .... No package or stack in context,Static checks summary: No errors or warnings, ROS Master does not appear to be running.
Online graph checks will not be run.
ROS_MASTER_URI is [http://localhost:11311]

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-16**:
also I try http://ias.cs.tum.edu/kb/wiki/index.php/Reasoning_about_actions It work except this instruction '?- owl_parse('owl/pancake-making.owl', false, false, true).' ... I get this error "ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: owl_parse/4 (DWIM could not correct goal)" ... also It is really exist!

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-16**:
also I try http://ias.cs.tum.edu/kb/wiki/index.php/Reasoning_about_actions It work except this instruction '?- owl_parse('owl/pancake-making.owl', false, false, true).' ... I get this error "ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: owl_parse/4 (DWIM could not correct goal)" ... also It is really exist!

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-18**:
@Ricky I get false, I think I have to read at SWI-Prolog, I Will start from HOWTO collection and , then try again. Do you recommend any else ?! Thanks

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-11-18**:
I don't understand why you have to read SWI-Prolog? After running rosrun rosprolog rosprolog mod_vis you'll see the prompt that enables you to use owl_parse(). See this:[http://i.imgur.com/CBTMP.png](https://i.imgur.com/CBTMP.png)

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-19**:
OK Thanks It is worked

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-11-19**:
Good~  : )

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-23**:
@Ricky It always give me false ?! and I am sure that I write the path correctly so What ?!

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-11-25**:
I got false too. But I can still view the parsed instances in visualziation_canvas, so I think it's not a serious problem. I am not sure if there's anything wrong with false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The command

```
owl_parse('home/amal/pizza.owl', false, false, true).
```

should be used after you started the knowrob system by

```
rosrun rosprolog rosprolog mod_vis
```

The function you called is defined in owl_parser.pl of the package "thea"

```
owl_parse(URL, RDF_Load_Mode, OWL_Parse_Mode,Imports) :-
    (   RDF_Load_Mode=complete,!,rdf_retractall(_,_,_); true),
    retractall(rdf_db:rdf_source(_,_,_,_)),
    rdf_load_stream(URL,[URL],Imports),
    owl_parse(OWL_Parse_Mode).
```

It's some options, I don't understand the meaning of these arguments.If you are really interested in this, a way to understand them is to see where they are used. For example,
you can understand the meaning of "OWL_Parse_Mode" by tracing this

```
owl_parse(OWL_Parse_Mode).
```

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2012-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5